# How to use insertion sort to sort alphabetically?

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, insertion-sort

Hello I'm working on code that sorts an arraylist in alphabetical order, however the code I wrote is returning in reverse alphabetical order. Does anyone understand why?? I cant seem to figure it out, I'm a beginner programmer help would be appreciated!

```
public class InsertionSorting {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> color = new ArrayList<String>(5);
        color.add("White");
        color.add("Black");
        color.add("Red");
        color.add("White");
        color.add("Yellow");
        
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            System.out.println(color.get(i).toString());
        }
        System.out.println();
        insertionSort(color);
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            System.out.println(color.get(i).toString());
        }
    }
    
    public static ArrayList<String>
            insertionSort(ArrayList<String> a) {
        for (int i = 1; i < a.size(); i++) {
            String s = a.get(i);
            int j = i - 1;
            while (j >= 0 && s.compareTo(a.get(j)) > 0) {
                String y = a.get(j + 1);
                a.set(j + 1, a.get(j));
                a.set(j, y);
                j--;
            }
            String y = a.get(j + 1);
            y = s;
        }
        return a;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It works fine.  It is just sorting in reverse order.  To sort the other way change your `compare` equality.

```
while (j >= 0 && s.compareTo(a.get(j)) < 0) {
    String y = a.get(j + 1);
    a.set(j + 1, a.get(j));
    a.set(j, y);
    j--;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the second *for* in *main* to

```
for (int i = 4; i >= 0; i--){

    System.out.println(color.get(i).toString());

}
```

Or more easily you can use this in your *main*

```
ArrayList<String> colors = new ArrayList<String>(5);
colors.add("White");
colors.add("Black");
colors.add("Red");
colors.add("Brown");
colors.add("Yellow");

Collections.sort(colors);

for(String color : colors){

    System.out.println(color);

}
```

Comment: But this doesn't help to explain why the code in the Question is returning in reverse alphabetical order.